# Which ECMA java script standard does Nightwatch js supports?

Tags: nightwatch.js

Which ECMA java script standard does Nightwatch js supports in its latest release? I tried searching for this info in many other websites but couldn't get the same. Can anyone provide some info on this.

Comment: This is an invalid question. It's like asking: "If I print this document on my printer, what colour will the paper be?"

ECMAScript adherance is only relevant for the browsers and for javascript compilers/polyfills

Comment: Its a valid question. I saw a documentation for Node js that its supports JacaScript ECMA-262 specifications. 

Links:  https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

I want to know the same for Nightwatch js as its also built on Node js.

Comment: Node.js is standalone javascript runtime evaluation software. It's not a javascript library. In my analogy, Nightwatch js is the document, and Node.js is the printer.

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse to begin with. 
What I'm suggesting is that you should not confuse [a library for a runtime environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372852/meaning-of-runtime-environment-and-of-software-framework).
What I mean to say is; whether the browser supports ECMAScript 5 or ECMAScript 6 has nothing to do with the Nightwatch js libraries, it's **purely** about _your_ code and _your_ "environment".
The question you want to ask is: "Should I write javascript code that is not ECMAScript 5 conformant?". Which is also the question that has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use Nightwatch.js with `ECMAScript 5`. However, if your team is shifting to `ECMAScript 6`, then you can integrate tools like `Babel` or `Traceur`(popular Javascript transpilers) into your project. Writing Nightwatch tests directly using ECMAScript 6 is not advisable at this stage because some versions of browsers still don't support the latest JS standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I read in nightwatch js email list saying some work is going around this.Not sure when this will be available to users.

Comment: Yes, it's probably going to take some time. They still have several unresolved issues on different browsers with the latest javascript standard.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't support ECMA 6.

Several people use a `require babel` on the header of the files since they had multiple issues creating Promises on top of Selenium, however, bugs are expected.

[Reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nightwatchjs/5lxDWDb6ojU)